# Extraer el DPI o PPP de una imagen con php

Tags: php

Estoy intentando extraer la resolución de una imagen,
usando las líneas de código siguiente, pero no logro obtener el PPP correcto.

```
<?php
function calcularPPP($temporal){
          $archivo = fopen($temporal,'r');
                    $cadena = fread($archivo, filesize($temporal));
                    fclose($archivo);
                    $datos = bin2hex(substr($cadena,14, 4));
                    $ppp = substr($datos, 0, 4);
                    return hexdec($ppp);
}
echo 'El ppp es: '.calcularPPP('descarga.jpeg'); //imprime El ppp es: 42

?>
```

Muestro el PPP original de la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan compartir sus conocimientos.
Gracias.

Comment: Echa un vistazo a la doc. Tienes esta función https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.imageresolution.php para saber los DPI de una imagen. Quizás te sirva...

Comment: Creo que es necesario probar con una misma imagen de tu lado y del lado de los que intentan responder. Lo mismo, si probaste la respuesta y obtuviste algo diferente, por favor edita la pregunta e indica cuál fue el resultado. "No funciona" o "dio diferente" no sirve para saber qué sucede.

Comment: Quiero extraer el PPP de la imagen pero me arroja otro valor distinto al PPP de la imagen. Le muestro: **imagen: (https://imgur.com/a6ovYOT)** el resultado debería ser 300PPP

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tu problema puede venir al tratar con hexadecimales, no logro encontrar el error, pero este código funciona, saludos.

```php
<?php
function calcularPPP($temporal){
          $archivo = fopen($temporal,'r');
                    $cadena = fread($archivo, filesize($temporal));
                    fclose($archivo);

                    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($temporal);
                    echo "width: " . $width . "<br />";
                    echo "height: " .  $height;
}
 echo calcularPPP('descarga.jpeg');

?>
```

Comment: Estimado @Roberto Paillao, tengo imágenes con 300 PPP, pero al leerlo con aquel algoritmo me arroja otro número distinto. Me parece raro, porque para que reconozca esos 300 PPP, tengo que convertirlo todavía en linea **https://convert.town/image-dpi** ahí recién lo reconoce.

Comment: Con PHP, también puedes convertir imágenes, podrías partir por ahí, lo del algoritmo verificalo, yo hice un par de pruebas 
y funcionó sin problemas [imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34v21.png)

Comment: Con respecto al ancho y alto todo bien, el detalle es el PPP. Le muestro en **imagen: (https://imgur.com/a6ovYOT)** Debería de mostrar 300PPP

Comment: ok, si entiendo.